# How to add a reference to native COM library in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, com, clickonce

There is the [Deploying COM Components with ClickOnce](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165432%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) article in MSDN that says that native DLLs also could be referenced:

> To add a native reference, use the Add Reference command, then browse
>   to the manifest.

So, I'm trying to reference [Skype4COM](http://developer.skype.com/accessories) library. I've generated a manifest using **mt**
 tool. But when I try to reference this manifest, VS says me:

[image: Add Reference error].

What am I understand or I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What is the target platform selected for your visual studio project you are trying to add the reference to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing up *deploying* with *building*.  Adding a reference requires a type library or a DLL that contains a type library embedded inside the DLL.  Skype4com.dll has one but it has a problem which prevents it from being added through the Add Reference dialog.

Use the Visual Studio Command Prompt from the Start + Programs menu.  Use cd to navigate to the correct directory and type tlbimp skype4com.dll.  You'll get a warning that you can ignore as long as you are running 32-bit code.  Go back to VS and use Add Reference, Browse tab and select the generated SKYPE4COMLib.dll file.

Comment: will this still allow to use COM-library in isolated mode?

Comment: Yes.  But that's a separate issue.  Get it building first.  Isolation is a deployment detail.

Comment: so... it's building. But now, how to use this COM library in Isolated mode?